# when getting server members with await server.fetch_members().flatten() returns no member.activities value

Tags: python, discord.py

When I try and get all the members in a server and then try and get their activities value it returns none () for every user. I am using discord.py
my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)
@bot.eventclient.get_guild(guild_id)
async def on_ready():
    serverlist = await bot.fetch_guilds().flatten()
    for server in serverlist:
        async for _member in server.fetch_members():
            print(_member.activities)
    
bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem could have 2 solutions:

1: Do you have the members intent enabled on the [Discord developer page](https://discord.com/developers/applications)? if not, enable it.

2: I'm not Shure how `await bot.fetch_guilds().flatten()` Works. I always use `client.guilds` to get a list with all guilds. Maybe this helps you.

Comment: I have the intents enabled and im using await `bot.fetch_guilds().flatten()` because it returns an up to date list of guilds and not just the cached list that `client.guilds` collects on startup however `guild.members` does return the .activities value bot not `server.fetch_members()` even though they are trying to get the same thing just one is outdated. it seems like a discord api issue to me lol